# Flex 3: How Can I Work on a Copy of a Project?

Tags: apache-flex

I've got a Flex 3 project. It works fine. But, I'd like to make some major changes to it.

Is there a way to duplicate the project and work on the copy? It's critical that I don't screw-up the original. But, I'd like to make major changes to the copy.

I tried making a copy of the project and renaming it. But, when I try to import the copy into Flex Builder, it says: "A project with the same name already exists in your workspace. Rename or delete the existing project." -- even though I renamed the project file and the main mxml file.

Unfortunately, I don't have a subversion program set-up, and I think that it will be a hassle to do so. Is there an easy way to work on a copy of a project?

My project uses a mySQL database. I don't know if that makes any difference.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing first. You need to have a version management, if you are doing branching and merging. Creating local subversion repo is not that big a deal, but I use local git repository and it takes a minute to initialize a repository.(local)

Now on to your question. You can create a copy of your project and the reason why your IDE is complaining is you have copied  the project folders also ( project folders like .classpath and .project generated by your IDE). To make a copy, create a new project in your IDE and just copy the src folder ( and other versioned files  ). You should be fine then.

Comment: And by the way if you versioned your files using git, you do not have to worry about creating a copy. The workflow is pretty simple, create a brach, work on that branch, if you are happy with branch, merge to head (master) else revert your working copy to master.

Comment: I second that. You should really think about using a version control system like SVN or Git. It makes life a lot easier. Some companies offer free, private repositories (e.g. [Assembla Free Plans](http://offers.assembla.com/free/), which I use for my personal projects) if you don't want to set up your own server and worry about backups, software upgrades...

Comment: Hi doc_180, Thank you very much for your help. I'll look into Git. In the meantime, I tried starting a new project and then copying over the src and library files from the original project. I renamed the main mxml file with the new project's name and updated its references. But, when I run the copied project, I get a "This file cannot be launched" error. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you are using the flex builder.(or flash builder), right click on your main mxml file and  click set as default application. I believe that the main application.mxml is not set properly.

Comment: doc_180, Victory! I also had to change the compiler setting for the services-config.xml file. Thank you very much for the help.